# Ruby Gem to write to excel?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm currently writing a ruby script that will make changes to excel documents based off of certain criteria's I set. I've been using the ruby gem 'roo' to do the reading aspect of the script but haven't been able to find a suitable writer. I've tried RubyXL and spreadsheet but I haven't been able to get them to work. Is there a simpler alternative to writing or a better gem to use out there for writing to excel?

Comment: I made good experiences with [axlsx](https://rubygems.org/gems/axlsx)

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried [The Ruby Spreadsheet](https://github.com/zdavatz/spreadsheet)?

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'spreadsheet'

# Begin Test
print "Spreadsheet Test\n"

# Create the rows to be inserted
row_1 = ['A1', 'B1']
row_2 = ['A2', 'B2']

# Create a new Workbook
new_book = Spreadsheet::Workbook.new

# Create the worksheet
new_book.create_worksheet :name => 'Sheet Name'

# Add row_1
new_book.worksheet(0).insert_row(0, row_1)

# Write the file
new_book.write('test.xls')
```